# Spring RestTemplate escaping '&'

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am trying to make an REST call with a query parameter that has `&` in it.
I can do this call via Postman and it works. 
The url is `https://dev.apiwh.adidas.com/cpm/taxonomy/tags?filter=category-label eq "Body+%26+Mind"`

The problem is in the Java code.

```
    String param = "category-label eq \"" + name + "\"";;
    [...]
    String url = "https://dev.apiwh.adidas.com/cpm/taxonomy/tags";
    // Query parameters
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
            // Add query parameter
            .queryParam("filter",  "category-label eq \"" + name + "\"");
    URI uri = builder.buildAndExpand().toUri();

    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            uri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            entity,
            String.class);
```

Exception:

```
URI: https://dev.apiwh.adidas.com/cpm/taxonomy/tags
https://dev.apiwh.adidas.com/cpm/taxonomy/tags?filter=category-label%20eq%20%22Body%20&%20Mind%22
{"exception":"MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException","error":400,"message":"Invalid filter string. Valid filter: 'category-label eq \"value\"' or 'uuid eq \"value\"', 'collection-id eq \"value\"'or 'uuid in (\"value1\",\"value2\")'. \\, \", <, >, tabs and newlines are not allowed.","timestamp":"2019-02-27T09:06:05.203Z","status":"BAD_REQUEST"}
```

I have tried to provide url as a string `https://dev.apiwh.adidas.com/cpm/taxonomy/tags?filter=category-label eq "Body+%26+Mind"` There is still an error on the server side that `Body %26 Mind` is not valid.